# Finding tags with a particular string /char like "?" in the text filed of tags in python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to **scrape** a website for some processing - [weblink](http:///https://www.spykar.com/faq)

Trying to find "tags", only when "?" is present in the text part of it.
For this, I went to this [beautiful soup documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-function) and wrote a function like this

```
def find_quest(tag): 
    text = tag.text 
    str_text = str(text) 
    bool_ = False 
    for i in range(len(str_text)): 
        if str_text[i] == "?":
            bool_ = True 
            break 
    return bool_
```

But still not able to extract the tags- It is giving me everything as output, not only selected tags. Anyone having an idea how to do it?
Complete code

```py
def find_quest(tag): 
    text = tag.text 
    str_text = str(text) 
    bool_ = False 
    for i in range(len(str_text)): 
        if str_text[i] == "?":
            bool_ = True 
            break 
    return bool_

def get_bs4_tag(children_list):
    tag_i_list = []
    for i in range(len(children_list)):
        string_i = str(children_list[i])
        if children_list[i] == "bs4.element.Tag" or children_list[i] == "<class 'bs4.element.Tag'>":
            tag_i_list.append(i)

    return tag_i_list

def download_page(link):
    page = requests.get(link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
    children_list = [str(type(item)) for item in list(soup.children)]
    tag_i_list = get_bs4_tag(children_list)
    for i in tag_i_list:
        html = list(soup.children)[i] 
        x = list(html.find_all(find_quest))

download page("https://www.spykar.com/faq")
```

Comment: what does this `get_bs4_tag` return?

Comment: @Vitor bs4.element.Tag - question updated

Comment: just to make sure, you're trying to scrape all the FAQ questions in that website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use regular expression re. and find the text contains `?` and then get the parent.

```
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
page = requests.get("https://www.spykar.com/faq")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
for item in soup.find_all(text=re.compile("\?$")):
     print(item.parent)
```

**Output**:

```
<span>Q: Do I have to register to shop at www.spykar.com?</span>
<span>Q: Do I have to disclose my e-mail id and phone number for registration?</span>
<span>Q: How secure is shopping with www.spykar.com or Is my personal Information secure?</span>
<span>Q: Are there any charges for registration?</span>
<span>Q: How do I get a new password?</span>
<span>Q: Can I edit my personal information?</span>
<span>Q: What kind of payment option does www.spykar.com offer?</span>
<span>Q: How do I know of www.spykar.com latest news and promotions?</span>
<span>Q: I have received a few emails from www.spykar.com. What are Orders Received, Orders Processed and Payment Receipt?</span>
<span>Q: I'm missing an item from my order, what do I do?</span>
<span>Q: What do I do if I receive a faulty item in my order?</span>
<span>Q: I have an incorrect item in my order, what do I do?</span>
<span>Q: Can I change my order after I've placed it?</span>
<span>Q: How long would it take for me to receive the refund of the returned/cancelled product?</span>
<span>Q: Within how many days can I return the product?</span>
<span>Q: How can I raise a return request on Spykar website?</span>
<span>Q: How do I return multiple products from a single order?</span>
<span>Q: Does Spykar pick up the product I want to return from my location?</span>
<span>Q: Why was my return request declined?</span>
<span>Q: Why did the return pickup of my product fail?</span>
<span>Q: How do I request a pickup again if the first attempt failed?</span>
<span>Q: How long would it take for me to receive the refund of the returned/cancelled product?</span>
<span>Q: Can I cancel my order after I've placed it?</span>
<span>Q: How long would it take for me to receive the refund of the returned/cancelled product?</span>
<span>Q: How long would it take for me to receive the refund of the returned/cancelled product?</span>
<span>Q: How can I exchange products I bought from www.Spykar.com?</span>
<span>Q: When will I receive the products I have ordered?</span>
<span>Q: Are there any delivery charges?</span>
<span>Q: Does Spykar deliver products outside India?</span>
<span>Q: How can I get my order delivered faster?</span>
<span>Q: What is ActifClub?</span>
<span>Q: What happens in ActifClub?</span>
<span>Q: What does a customer need to do to become an ActifClub member?</span>
<span>Q: Is there any joining fee?</span>
<span>Q: When will I get the points credited?</span>
<span>Q: What is the value of the points?</span>
<span>Q: How do I get my Rewards Points?</span>
<span>Q: How can I redeem the points?</span>
<span>Q: Where can I check number of points I have?</span>
<span>Q: If I forget to collect points, what should I do?</span>
```

To get the text value.

```
print(item.parent.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

This may do what you want:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.spykar.com/faq'
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
content = soup.find('div', {'id': 'content'})
rows = content.find_all('div', {'class': 'row'})
for row in rows:
    texts = row.find_all('span')
    for text in texts:
        if '?' in text.text:
            print(text.text)
```

Comment: Thanks for that @Vitor but i need "Trying to find "tags", only when "?" is present in the text part of it."